# Implementing an Add method for an Array List in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, methods, arraylist

I keep getting an error telling me that `add(T)` is undefined for the type `T` when trying to add `add`:

```
package p07;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList<T extends Number>
{
    private T ArrayList;

    public MyList(T ArrayList)
    {
        this.ArrayList=ArrayList;
    }
    public void add(T x)
    {
        ArrayList.add(x);
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: You should use MyList().add() not T().add()

Answer (score 1):

You've incorrectly made the `ArrayList` a variable of type `T`. The line `private T ArrayList;` should be `private ArrayList<T> l;` where `l` would be the variable name.

The issue is that `ArrayList` is a generic type, so when you pass your generic type to it, you must pass it through `ArrayList<T>`. `T ArrayList` is a variable called `ArrayList` of type `T`.

You have to change this everywhere: every `T` you've shown in this snippet should be an `ArrayList<T>`.